# Reset an Array of forms in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a form comment section whereby a user can reply to a comment. Each comment has a form with a reply box. Am getting the comments from the database and running the following loop.

```
@foreach($responses as $response)
<form action="{{action('DiscussionController@postAnswerQuestion',[$entry_year, $grade_id, $subject_id, $question_id])}}" method="post" name="replyForm" class="commentForm" >
<li>{{$response->answer}}</li>
<div id="reply">
<input type="text" name="reply" value="" placeholder="Reply" >
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="response_id" value="{{$response->id}}">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{{csrf_token()}}}">
<input type="submit" name="" value="reply"   >

</form>

@endforeach
```

Am using jquery and ajax to submit the page and I want to reset a form field when a user has submitted the reply.

When I use

```
document.forms.replyForm.reset();
```

only the first form is reset. The other forms in the loop are not being reset.

How should I go about it so that each form is reset after a user submits a reply.

Comment: You will find that `document.forms` is in fact an array. So make use of that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason is  `document.forms` return an array but you are only reset first form try to loop each form:-

```
$('[name="replyForm"]').each(function(){
   this.reset();
});
```

OR using javascript:-

```
 var forms = document.forms;
    for (var i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        if (forms[i].name == "replyForm") {
            forms[i].reset();
        };
    }
```

[Javascript Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XPMjK/93/)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XPMjK/91/)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :

> $('.commentForm').trigger("reset");

Answer (score 1):

As you have a class name on your form:

```
class='commentForm'
```

you can use it:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('commentForm').reset();
```

because `.getElementsByClassName()` returns a collection of elements it will work to reset all of them which have the class name `commentForm`.

with `.querySelectorAll()`:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.commentForm').reset();
```

Answer (score 1):

**For JavaScript**:

Add the common class for each `form`, because you are running the loop.

suppose `formR` is the common class for all rendered `form`.

**Code:**

```
formRC=document.getElementsByClassName("formR");
for(i=0;i<formRC.length;i++){
    formRC[i].reset();;
}
```

And for **jQuery** you can use:

```
$('.formR').each(function(){
   this.reset();
});
```